# Torquebox not finding Gems bundled in my knob file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, torquebox

I've packaged my Rails app as a Knob file, and am trying to deploy it into a running Torquebox server in our QA environment.

When starting up the application, I get the following error:

```
14:24:24,513 ERROR [org.torquebox.core.runtime] (pool-3-thread-1) Error during execution:     ENV['RAILS_ROOT']=RACK_ROOT
ENV['RAILS_ENV']=RACK_ENV
require %q(org/torquebox/web/rails/boot)
: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (GemNotFound) Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the   sources
at RUBY.materialize(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92)    at org.jruby.RubyArray.map!(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2441)
at RUBY.materialize(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85)    at   RUBY.specs(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133) at RUBY.specs_for(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178)   at RUBY.requested_specs(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:167) at RUBY.requested_specs(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18) at RUBY.setup(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13)   at RUBY.setup(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:119)  at RUBY.(root)(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17)    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1085)
at Kernel.require(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55)  at Kernel.require(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53)  at RUBY.(root)(/opt/torquebox-3.1.0/jboss/auth-platform/tmp/vfs/temp8f8160d3b3c8c411/auth-platform.knob-6a482ebab5ccfc78/config/boot.rb:1)  at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1085)
at Kernel.require(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55)  at Kernel.require(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53)  at RUBY.(root)(/opt/torquebox-3.1.0/jboss/auth-platform/tmp/vfs/temp8f8160d3b3c8c411/auth-platform.knob-6a482ebab5ccfc78/config/boot.rb:9)  at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1085)
at Kernel.require(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55)  at Kernel.require(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53)  at RUBY.(root)(/opt/torquebox-3.1.0/jboss/auth-platform/tmp/vfs/temp8f8160d3b3c8c411/auth-platform.knob-6a482ebab5ccfc78/config/application.rb:1)   at org.jruby.RubyKernel.load(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101)
at RUBY.(root)(/opt/torquebox-3.1.0/jboss/auth-platform/tmp/vfs/temp8f8160d3b3c8c411/auth-platform.knob-6a482ebab5ccfc78/config/application.rb:1)   at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1085)
at Kernel.require(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55)  at Kernel.require(/opt/torquebox/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53)  at RUBY.(root)(/opt/torquebox-3.1.0/jboss/auth-platform/tmp/vfs/temp8f8160d3b3c8c411/auth-platform.knob-6a482ebab5ccfc78/config/environment.rb:1)
```

In short, bundler is trying to find rake 10.3.2, which is included in my knob file under `vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/rake-10.3.2`.

Is the right place for gems to placed? Why isn't torquebox including this in the file?

I've tried auto-deploying by dropping the knob file into the deployments directory as well as through the Web admin console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run torquebox with the package_gems switch from the project directory to include all bundler gem dependencies in the knob artifact - http://torquebox.org/documentation/3.0.0/torquebox-cmd.html

```
torquebox archive --package_gems
```